# Do functions in template specialization by value also need to have <VALUE> in their declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I am writing a class that has template specialization by value and was wondering if the Constructor and the methods in the template specialization also need to have < VALUE > in their declaration.

In other words, which of the following two examples are correct?

A)

```
template <int i>
class MyClass {};

template <>
class MyClass<0> {
  public: 
    MyClass<0>() {         // specialization value included
      // initialize stuff
    }
    void PrintClass<0> () {     // specialization value included
      // print stuff 
    }
 }
```

B)

```
template <int i>
class MyClass {};

template <>
class MyClass<0> {
  public: 
    MyClass() {            // specialization value NOT included
      // initialize stuff
    }
    void PrintClass () {        // specialization value NOT included
      // print stuff 
    }
 }
```

Comment: There will be an injected-class-name `MyClass` referring to `MyClass<0>`.

Comment: @dyp absent nasty macros, they probably are ;-)

Comment: @dyp: Added return types now. Thanks

Comment: @dyp: probably a n00b question but what does that mean - "there will be an injected-class-name MyClass referring to MyClass<0>"?

Comment: @raovgarimella everywhere inside the class `MyClass` means `MyClass<i>` for a class template, or `MyClass<0>` for the specialization for `i==0`. the name `MyClass` is literally "injected" into its own scope.